# PHP user alert to change $_SESSION variable with break routine

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a script that require user interaction to over write a SESSION variable with a yes/no option.

A response of yes results in a simple header redirect (I can already do this).

```
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('You already are subscribed to a plan, would you like to change your plan at this time?')
            window.location.href='../index.php?p=payment';
    </SCRIPT>");
```

But a response of no should break the subroutine and 'complete' the rest of the PHP script.

How do I present a user with a 'yes/no' option to change a session variable, where 'no' results in a PHP script continuation?

Comment: You need to look into ajax; make a request from javascript to the server without leaving the page.

Comment: @jeroen yeah, I started to ponder after I posted "programmer/me is trying to do something st00pid and that's why I can't think of a way". Either AJAX to feed the input back to my serverside app, or forget the 'yes/no' option and leave the alert as a final 'are you sure?' with an 'ok' and leave it at that.

Comment: It depends if you need to make a server request in all cases or not. If you do, you need ajax, if not, you can probably get around it with your redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `alert` for this purpose is not appropriate

Better use `confirm` box of javascript  which displays a confirm box with a **yes** and **no** option and no options stops the event to happen

```
<script>
     if(confirm('You already are subscribed to a plan, would you like to change your plan at this time?'))
     { 
           window.location.href='../index.php?p=payment';
     }
</script>
```

this will only work if the user hits **Yes**